# Removing duplicate entries in a vector, when entries are complex and rounding errors are causing problems

Tags: matlab

I want to remove duplicate entries from a vector on Matlab. The problem I'm having is that rounding errors are stopping the inbuilt Matlab function 'unique' from working properly. Ideally I'd like a way to set some sort of tolerance on the 'unique' function, or a small procedure that will remove the duplicates otherwise. If both the real and imaginary parts of two entries differ by less than 0.0001, then I'm happy to consider them equal. How can I do this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A simple approximation would be to round the numbers and the use the indices returned by unique:

```
X = ... (input vector)
[b, i] = unique(round(X / (tolerance * (1 + i))));
output = X(i);
```

(you can probably replace `b` with `~` depending on your Matlab version).

it won't quite have the behaviour you want, since it is possible that two numbers are very close but will be rounded differently. I think you could mitigate this by doing:

```
X = ... (input vector)
[b, ind] = unique(round(X / (tolerance * (1 + i))));
X = X(ind);
[b, ind] = unique(round(X / (tolerance * (1 + i)) + 0.5 * (1 + i)));
X = X(ind);
```

This will round them twice, so any numbers that are exactly on a rounding boundary will be caught by the second `unique`.
There is still some messiness in this - some numbers will be affected as though the tolerance was doubled. But it might be sufficient for your needs.

The alternative is probably a `for` loop:

```
X = sort(X);
last = X(1);
indices = ones(numel(X), 1);
for j=2:numel(X)
  if X(j) > last + tolerance * (1 + i)
    last = X(j) + tolerance * (1 + i) / 2;
  else
    indices(j) = 0;
  end
end
X = X(logical(indices));
```

I think this has the best behaviour you can expect (because you want to represent the vector by as few unique values as possible - when there are lots of numbers that differ by less than the tolerance level, there may be multiple ways of splitting them. This algorithm does so greedily, starting with the smallest).

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain the below ill always assume any values closer than 1e-8 are equal. Simply replace 1e-8 with  whatever value you want.

```
% unique function that assumes 1e-8 is equal
function [out, I] = unique(input, first_last)

threshold = 1e-8;
if nargin < 2
    first_last = 'last';
end
[out, I] = sort(input);
db = diff(out);
k = find(abs(db) < threshold);
if strcmpi(first_last, 'last')
    k2 = min(I(k), I(k+1));
elseif strcmpi(first_last, 'first')
    k2 = max(I(k), I(k+1));
else
    error('unknown flag option for unique, must be first or last');
end
k3 = true(1, length(input));
k3(k2) = false;
out = out(k3(I));
I = I(k3(I));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The following might serve your purposes. Given X, an array of complex doubles, it sorts them, then checks whether the absolute value differences between elements is within the complex tolerance, real_tol and imag_tol. It removes elements that satisfy this tolerance.

```matlab
function X_unique = unique_complex_with_tolerance(X,real_tol,imag_tol)
     X_sorted = sort(X); %Sorts by magnitude first, then imaginary part.

     dX_sorted = diff(X_sorted);
     dX_sorted_real = real(dX_sorted);
     dX_sorted_imag = imag(dX_sorted);

     remove_idx = (abs(dX_sorted_real)<real_tol) & (abs(dX_sorted_imag)<imag_tol);

     X_unique = X_sorted;
     X_unique(remove_idx) = [];
return
```

Note that this code will remove *all* elements which satisfy this difference tolerance. For example, if X = [1+i,2+2i,3+3i,4+4i], real_tol = 1.1, imag_tol = 1.1, then this function will return only one element, X_unique = [4+4i], even though you might consider, for example, X_unique = [1+i,4+4i] to also be a valid answer.